# Crit damage in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

If I am playing with Bounty Hunter or PA and I have bought a Crystalis, for example, will the damage will be better or worse because it is lower than the one of the skills of the hero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Critical hits](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Critical_strike) cannot stack with each other.  The higher of the proc/damage wins.

[For example](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Item_passive_stacking):

> If a hero buys both a Crystalys and a Daedalus , on every hit the hero has a 20% chance of proccing a critical attack from Daedalus, a 15% chance from Crystalys, and a 5% chance of proccing both. Unlike the independent stacking, Daedalus overrides the Crystalys in the last case, because it has a higher critical damage multiplier and only one critical can proc on one hit.

In your case, Jinada will proc 100% of the time, and Crystalys will proc 15% of the time, but will be ignored even if it procs since Jinada does more damage.

Comment: Jinada will proc 100% of the time only if it's off cooldown... So the Crystalys wont be ignored but it is clearly suboptimal

Comment: @T_O yea, that's what I meant.  Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: So @z' is the conclusion that there's no point building Crystalys on Bounty?

Comment: Generally stacking crits is not optimal as there is a diminishing return effect after the first critical strike item or skill. On Bounty you have a guaranteed crit every few seconds (depending on the level of Jinada), damage items or minus armor ones are way more effective on him.